# How to set in the Table methods field's properties from code?

Tags: properties, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to set field properties , in table method from code.

I would like to do as a *Form*

in `modifiedField` *Table* method, I wolud like to insered look like this code:

```
if(this.FieldControl == "valueToBlock")
{
    // I want to set here the field property 
    //this.Field_II allowEdit(false); 
}
```

It's possible to set the property from code in Table method ?

thanks community,

enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.datasource.aspx) result on the buffer. The result is [FormDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formdatasource.aspx) if buffer source is from client form.

If record changes you have to re-calculate this (create new method and call it from the table *modifiedFiled* and form DS *active*).

```cs
public void modifiedField(FieldId _fieldId)
{
    FormDataSource fds;    
    super(_fieldId);    
    switch (_fieldId)
    {
        case fieldNum(TableName,FieldI):
            if (this.isFormDataSource())
            {
                fds = this.dataSource();
                fds.object(fieldNum(MyTable, Field_II)).allowEdit(this.Field_I != "valueToBlock");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```